# Make a rotating background image button

Tags: android, android-animation, imagebutton, image-rotation

I want to make basicly angry birds "buy button" which has a repeatedly rotating background.

[image]

For easly tell, I have made a image table how can I combine that

[image]

Comment: I would put ImageView behind the button (both in a FrameLayout container) and rotate it with an animation.

Comment: Actually it look long.. can I use image background as a animation like this `android:background="@anim/rotate_image1` `android:src="@drawable/button_image2`